# Return datatype Angle inside static function

Tags: java

The class `Angle` should create an angle in degrees and radiant values.

I want to return this data type `Angle`, as a return value of this static function `degrees`.
Why does my current code not compile?

```
public class Angle {

    private static double gradmass;
    private static double bogenmass;

    public static Angle degrees(double angle) {
        Angle angle1;
        gradmass = Math.toDegrees(angle);
        bogenmass = angle;
        angle1.setDegrees(bogenmass);
        angle1.setRadians(gradmass);
        return angle1;
    }

    public static Angle radians(double angle) {
        bogenmass = Math.toRadians(angle);
        gradmass = angle;
    }

    public double getDegrees() {
        return gradmass;
    }

    public double setDegrees(double gradM) {
        gradmass = gradM;
        return gradmass;
    }

    public double getRadians() {
        return bogenmass;
    }

    public double setRadians(double bogenM) {
        bogenmass = bogenM;
        return gradmass;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you don't use a static method here - what you need to create is a constructor. Constructors take in params and spit out an instance of your desired class (Angle, here). Making this change will give you errors with `private static double gradmass;
    private static double bogenmass;` . Fix that by removing the static keyword from those too. Im guessing you are going to have many different angles with different values in your project, in that case your variables are non-static by nature. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help @njari.
I found this solution, because I have to stay without constructor and with my static functions:

```
 public static Angle degrees(double angle) {
            Angle angleD = new Angle();
            gradmass = angle;
            bogenmass = Math.toRadians(angle);
            angleD.setDegrees(bogenmass);
            angleD.setRadians(gradmass);
            return angleD;
        }
```

Comment: its great that you answered your own question. please also accept it, so this question is marked as answered